# Запрос меняется на OPTIONS

Tags: javascript, java, сервер, запрос

Есть сервер на джаве, пишу к нему сайт. При отправке запроса POST выдает

*Запрос из постороннего источника заблокирован: Политика одного источника запрещает чтение удаленного ресурса на http://localhost:8080/lambdas. (Причина: неудача канала CORS preflight).*

Но доступ вроде разрешен.

Метод запроса почему-то оказывается OPTIONS. Почему такое происходит, как исправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это не надо исправлять - так и должно быть. Кроссдоменные запросы кроме get предваряются options-запросами, чтобы браузер понял, можно ли вообще посылать такой запрос. Сервер должен обработать options-запрос и послать соответствующие разрешающие заголовки, только после этого браузер пошлёт сам post-запрос.

Comment: хорошо, как обработать, кроме того, чтобы прописать

response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
     response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true");

Comment: Перечисленные тобой заголовки несовместимы. Либо звёздочка и credentials лесом, либо конкретный домен (или список доменов) и credentials. Вроде хром в консоли пишет предупреждение про это.

Comment: извиняюсь, у меня конкретный домен, здесь заменил просто

Comment: @МаврикийНиколаевич, allow methods post, allow content type тот, который собираешься слать, allow headers для всех кастомных заголовков (возможно даже, для content-type). Вроде хром в консоли хорошо расписывает, чего ему не хватило, чтобы послать запрос, не?

Comment: не понял, что вы сейчас перечислили? в любом случае хром ничего не говорит(

Comment: в заголовках ответа все это есть

Answer (score 0):

//пишется класс фильтра

```
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;

public class CrossDomainFilter implements Filter
{ 
@Override
  public void init(FilterConfig filterConfig) throws ServletException 
  {}

@Override
  public void destroy() 
  {}

  public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException 
  {
    HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) servletRequest;
    HttpServletResponse response = (HttpServletResponse) servletResponse;

    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods","GET,POST,OPTIONS");
    response.addHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Headers","Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");

    if(request.getMethod().equals("OPTIONS")) 
    {
      response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_OK);
      return;
    }
    chain.doFilter(request, servletResponse);
  }
}
```

//регистрируется в web.xml на нужный сервлет или адрес (в примере сервлет)

**//!!!ЗАПИСЬ ДЕЛАЕТСЯ В САМОМ НАЧАЛЕ!!!**

```
<filter>
  <filter-name>Cross Domain Filter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>CrossDomainFilter</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>Cross Domain Filter</filter-name>
  <servlet-name>MyServlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

//КОД 100% РАБОЧИЙ